Posting a React Object to a C# Endpoint generating a 400 error
I have a form that submits two text boxes...
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
 <input type="text" name="name"  onChange={handleInput} />
 <input type="text" name="desc"  onChange={handleInput} />
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

I am setting and sending the values like this...
 const [post, setPost] = useState({
 name: '',
 desc:''
})

const handleInput = (event) => {
  setPost({ ...post, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
 }


const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();


await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/cookie',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data: {post},
    dataType: 'json'
});
}

I verified that {post} has this as per what I submit:  {"post":{"name":"test","desc":"this"}}
But the C# endpoint I'm using generates a 400 error.  Bad Request.
  [ApiController]
  [Route("[controller]")]
  public class CookieController : ControllerBase
  {
  [HttpPost(Name = "")]
  public IEnumerable<Cookie> Post([FromBody] JObject data)
  {
  ...
  }
  }

This is the class..
public class Cookie
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Desc { get; set; }
  ...
}

Am I using the wrong signature to access the React object I'm posting?

try posting it without using JSON.stringify, data: {post}, according to another SO article, axios already does the stringify of json data., so you are probably getting a double serialized string, which is not deserialized correctly in the backend: axios-post-request-with-json-data

Same result.  400 error    This is what the {post} is in the console...
{"post":{"name":"test","desc":"this"}}

are you able to set a breakpoint on your call to axios and inspect what is being set to the data attribute?

should be data: post

I am.   It's what is being printed to the console.  The values from the text box assigned to the correct variables.

Amila,  same result.   400  Bad Request.   I thought the signature may be wrong?

OK I think I got it!  The signature needs the Class name as a type:  [FromBody] Cookie data   But both of the suggestions here are also working.  No stringfy.   and post without the brackets.  Thanks!
